# SQL insert into autoincrement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an inection

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_client_name, order_client_surname, order_client_bdate, order_cat_id, order_service_id, order_service_cost) 
    VALUES ('РАрарарара', 'Рахимжанов', '1997-01-31', 1, 12, (select ser_cost FROM services WHERE ser_id=12));
```

I won't write 'ser_id=...' in select, so can i make autopaste in ser_id what i send in Values 'order_service_id'

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_client_name, order_client_surname, order_client_bdate, order_cat_id, order_service_id, order_service_cost) 
    VALUES ('РАрарарара', 'Рахимжанов', '1997-01-31', 1, 12, (select ser_cost FROM services WHERE ser_id=order_service_id));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  What issue are you having?

Comment: I think you've missed the point of a relational database - you don't replicate data from from other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want `insert . . . select`?

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_client_name, order_client_surname, order_client_bdate, order_cat_id, order_service_id, order_service_cost) 
    SELECT 'РАрарарара', 'Рахимжанов', '1997-01-31', 1, x.order_service_id, s.ser_cost
    FROM services s CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT 12 as order_service_id) x
    WHERE ser_id = x.order_service_id;
```

You can list the parameters in a subquery, so you only have to pass them once.

That said, it is usually a bad idea to repeat data between tables.  In general, you don't need the cost if you have the id.  The one exception is if the cost changes over time through updates -- then keeping the cost at the time of the order does make sense.